# My chaos of a code. Random color and size circles

Tags: java, swing, random

```java
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

public class keyExample extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    double x = 0, y = 0;

    double changeX = 0, changeY = 0;

    public keyExample() {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);

        setFocusable(true);

        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

    }

    private static final int N_CIRCLES = 10;

    private static final double MIN_RADIUS = 5;

    private static final double MAX_RADIUS = 50;

    public void run() {
        Random gen = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < N_CIRCLES; i++) {

            double r = gen.nextDouble(MIN_RADIUS, MAX_RADIUS);
            double x = gen.nextDouble(0, getWidth() - 2 * r);
            double y = gen.nextDouble(0, getHeight() - 2 * r);

            Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, 2 * r, 2 * r);
            circle.setFilled(true);


            int red = gen.nextInt(256);
            int green = gen.nextInt(256);
            int blue = gen.nextInt(256);

            Color backColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

            pane.add(panel);

        }
        add(circle);
    }
}
```

I am supposed to create a code that produces circles with random colors and sizes. While tweaking with some parts and another. I have created this mess that I cannot comprehend. Please help me fixing the codes so that I will produce my intended outcome.

Answer (score 1):

So, first off, there is no `Random#nextDouble(min, max)`, you can tell this by reading through the JavaDocs.

So, a quick scan of the JavaDocs for [`Random#nextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble()) says

> Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed double value between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.

This means that `nextDouble` is going to return a "random" number from `0.0` to `1.0`.  This might not sound useful, but you'd be surprised.

Now, you're going to have to roll your own min/max logic.  Not to hard.  Start by calculating the range between the two values, use the value from `Random#nextDouble` and multiple it by "range" and add in the minimum, easy.

```
double range = MAX_RADIUS - MIN_RADIUS;
double r = MIN_RADIUS + (gen.nextDouble() * range);
```

I don't know what `Circle` is, you've not provided that so, move on.

This `pane.add(panel);` seems like a sure recipe for disaster.  I'm assuming `panel` is component, but you can't add a component to itself.

Assuming that `Circle` is some kind of component, then `add(circle);` is outside of the `for-loop`, so it won't do much, as the reference to `circle` is only valid within the `for-loop` context.